# PendingIntent is launching main activity instead of PendingIntent Activity When Screen Is Locked

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-pendingintent

I have a `Service` that is listening in the background for an event that will launch an `Activity` B through a `PendingIntent`. Everything works fine. But when I lock the screen, and trigger the event, the `PendingIntent` fires the main `Activity` A , and `Activity` B never gets fired (unless `Activity` A has been fired first).

Logging the problem. When I hit the back button, I am destroying both `Activity` A and `Activity` B. And when I trigger the event, The main activity is created and resumed. Is there a way to bypass that? Also, I am guessing that locking the screen has an effect on the app that I am missing.

Thanks.

Comment: Please put some code snippet so we can help.

Comment: code is all over the place. It is really difficult to show. But abstractly, can you fire an activity (that is not the main activity) even if the app is shut down?

Comment: Also, what does locking the screen do to the app?